# SQL inner joins on three tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have three tables that needs to be checked in order to find out on which courses professor is active.

1. table_teacher
2. table_course; and
3. table_teacher_holds_course

table_teacher looks like this:

```
username | title
---------+----------
john     | professor
mark     | assistant
```

table_course looks like this:

```
 course_code | course_name | semester | school_year
-------------+-------------+----------+------------
 course_code1| course1     |semester1 | 2015
 course_code2| course2     |semester2 | 2015
 course_code3| course3     |semester3 | 2015
```

table_teacher_holds_course looks like this:

```
username | course_code
---------+-------------
 john    |course_code1
 mark    |course_code2
```

and when I have professors username when he logs on the page, I would like to do left inner join on these three tables in order to show professors courses from table_course

Can someone help me with this, because it is first time to me to use sql to join search in several tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join on the tables common fields

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_teacher t
INNER JOIN table_teacher_holds_course hc ON t.username = hc.username
INNER JOIN table_course c ON hc.course_code = c.course_code
```

Relevant example:

```
SELECT t.title, t.username, c.course_code, c.course_name, c.semester, c.school_year 
FROM table_teacher t
INNER JOIN table_teacher_holds_course hc ON t.username = hc.username
INNER JOIN table_course c ON hc.course_code = c.course_code
WHERE t.username = 'John'
```

Result:

```
title      username course_code  course_name semester  school_year 
professor  John     course_code1 course1     semester1 2015
```

Comment: Typo, missing JOIN keyword.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! I will try with this !